# get the size and other info with the "du" command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, uniq, du

I'm doing a little script on bash, which shows the total size in mb, the number of files, the number of the folder and the name of folder.
I have almost everything except the size in mb

```
du -a -h | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c
```

It shows something like this:

```
  4 01 folder 01
  6 02 folder 02
 11 03 folder 03
 13 04 folder 04
 16 05 folder 05
 .....
 15 13 folder 13
  1 5.7G    .
```

as you see, the sort is: number of files, number of folder and name.

I want this:

```
  300M 4 01 folder 01
  435M 6 02 folder 02
  690M 11 03 folder 03
  780M 13 04 folder 04
  1.6G 16 05 folder 05
 .....
 15 13 folder 13
  1 5.7G    .
```

thank you in advance.

PD there is some way to show the name over each column like this?

```
  M    F  # name
  300M 4 01 folder 01
  435M 6 02 folder 02
  690M 11 03 folder 03
  780M 13 04 folder 04
  1.6G 16 05 folder 05
 .....
 15 13 folder 13
  1 5.7G    .
```

Comment: "there is some way to show the name over each column like this?" Yes, use `echo`.

Comment: Show some code instead of just one-liner you've already put there.

Comment: the only code I have is du -a -h | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
echo -e "Size\tFiles\tDirectory"; paste <(du -sh ./*/ | sort -k2 | cut -f1) <(find ./*/ | cut -d/ -f2 | uniq -c | sort -k2 | awk '{print ($1-1)"\t"$2}') | sort -nk2
```

Sample output:

```
Size    Files   Directory
172M    36      callrecords
17M     747     manual
83M     2251    input
7.5G    16867   output
```

**Explanation:**

Add the header:

```
echo -e "Size\tFiles\tDirectory";
```

<(COMMAND) is a structure which allows the output of a command to be used as if it were a file. [Paste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_%28Unix%29) takes 2 files, and outputs them side by side. So we are pasting together the outputs of two commands. The first is this:

```
<(du -sh ./*/ | sort -k2 | cut -f1)
```

Which simply finds the size of subfolders of the current folder, summarising anything inside. This is then sorted according to the names of the files/folders, and then the first column is taken.  This gives us a list of the sizes of subfolders of the current folder, sorted by their name.

The second command is this:

```
<(find ./*/ | cut -d/ -f2 | uniq -c | sort -k2 | awk '{print ($1-1)"\t"$2}')
```

This is similar to your original command - it finds folders below the current directory, truncates the names to include only the first sublevel, then counts them to give a list of sub-folders of the current folder, and the number of files within each. This is then sorted by the folder names, and the awk command formats the results and also subtracts 1 from the file count for each folder (as the folder itself is included). We can then paste the results together to get the (almost) final output.

Finally, we use **sort -nk2** on the output of the paste command to sort by number on the 2nd field - ie the number of files.

Comment: yes! that's basically what I want! thank you very much, and it's really helpfull the explanation too!!